# How to configure KafkaClient without use of environment

Tags: java, apache-kafka, oauth, configuration, jaas

I have this configuration in file kafka_jaas.conf:

```
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  oauth.token.endpoint.uri="uri"
  oauth.client.id="uid"
  oauth.client.secret="secret";
};
```

And add it to client configuration like this:

```
  client-config {
    bootstrap.servers = ${bootstrap.servers}
    schema.registry.url = ${schema.registry.url}
    security{
        protocol = "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
        sasl.mechanism = "OAUTHBEARER"
        sasl.jaas.config = "absolute/path/to/kafka_jaas.conf"
    }
  }
```

But I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
```

Can I fix it without adding system property manually just by using configuration files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config",...)` at runtime by parsing your config. It won't be automatic. But if you have access to the deployment environment, using JVM flags is more preferable